# Factoring Pointer Error in C programming

Tags: c, pointers, factors

So i'm having trouble making a program that asks the user to enter a number and then using that number I must increase the value of the pointer towards two_count and three_count. These are counter the factors of two's and three's in the number entered.

For example if the user input 2, then the program should spit out
"There have been 1 factor of 2 and 0 factors of 3"
Then the user can input 0 to exit program

What I have so far is

```
include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int* two_count;
    int* three_count;
    int num;

    while(two_count >= 0 || three_count >= 0)
    {
        printf("Enter a number: \n");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        if(num % 2)
        {
            two_count++;
        }
        else if(num % 3)
        {
            three_count++;
        }
        else if(num == 0)
        {
            printf("Thank you for playing, enjoy your day!\n");
            break;
        }

        printf("So far, there have been %d factors of 2 and %d factors of   3\n", two_count, three_count);
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: why did you declare the two counters as int pointers instead of int variables?

Comment: The program needs to have pointers, how would i go about doing that?

Comment: They have to be linked to pointers to hold the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use pointers, you can do it like this

```
int two_count = 0;
int* two_count_ptr = &two_count;
int three_count = 0;
int* three_count_ptr = &three_count;
```

Then, for retrieving value and incrementing you would need to dereference the pointer

```
while(*two_count_ptr >= 0 || *three_count_ptr >= 0)

(*two_count_ptr)++;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, I just though about what was said earlier about the pointers, why do we need them and I figured that we have to use another method call in the program.      void update_counts(int value, int* two_count, int* three_count);

Comment: I see, that makes more sense.